# How to execute command with parameters containing back slash, double quotes with help of C# in foreground?

Tags: c#

How to execute command with parameters containing  back slash, double quotes with help of C# in foreground?
Example:
C:\FolderPath\STSApp.exe /rc:TestRun /param:x="abc" /param:y="pqr"

Comment: what went wrong when you tried?

Comment: if you need to escape them in a string, use backslash, like "/param:x=\"abc\""

Answer (score 1):

You need to "escape" the path correctly. Change the double quotes for single quotes.

```
var x = @"C:\FolderPath\STSApp.exe /rc:TestRun /param:x='abc' /param:y='pqr'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use @ without any other changes in your command.

Example:

```
string command = @"C:\FolderPath\STSApp.exe /rc:TestRun /param:x="abc" /param:y="pqr"";
```